# "addTarget:self action:@selector" :: NSArray works, but pointers fail?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

"addTarget:self action:@selector"     ::   NSArray works, but pointers fail on the callBack routine?  But calling a routine from viewDidLoad works for both NSArray and pointers?  What is different about "addTarget:self action:@selector" callBack??

here is a code snippet:

thanks for looking...

file.h

```
NSArray *nsarrA;
NSString **p_nssB;
```

file.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    nsarrA = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",nil]; 

    p_nssB = (NSString**)malloc(10*sizeof(NSString*));
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        p_nssB[i]=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    }

    [self viewMenu];
}


- (void) viewMenu {    
    UIButton *uibtnMenu = [uibtnMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(actionMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [uiviewMenu addSubview:uibtnMenu];

    NSLog(@"nsarrA: %@ %@ %@", [nsarrA objectAtIndex:0], [nsarrA objectAtIndex:1], [nsarrA objectAtIndex:2]);//<--works
    NSLog(@"p_nssB: %@ %@ %@", p_nssB[0], p_nssB[1], p_nssB[2]);//<--Works
}


- (void) actionMenu:  (UIButton *) uibtnMenu{
    NSLog(@"nsarrA: %@ %@ %@", [nsarrA objectAtIndex:0], [nsarrA objectAtIndex:1], [nsarrA objectAtIndex:2]);//<--works
    NSLog(@"p_nssB: %@ %@ %@", p_nssB[0], p_nssB[1], p_nssB[2]);//<--fails(drops out of App)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocate with [NSString stringWithFormat:] the instance is autoreleased. It will be released by the next event cycle. You'll need to retain the instance.

So either do:

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] retain];
```

or:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", i];
```

Also, when you release the file.m object you'll need to do:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    [p_nssB[i] release];
}
```

Comment: Or better, use an NSArray. If you're going to be storing objects in C arrays, you need to have a very solid idea of how your objects' memory manage picture looks or you're going to either leak or end up with dangling pointers.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I was able to expand on your solution to solve me problem.

Comment: @Kristen Martinson: A leak is when memory gets into a state where it cannot be properly freed. For example, a loop like `while(1) malloc(10000000)` would leak like crazy. On the iPhone, where memory is scarce, a leak often translates into a crash. A dangling pointer is the opposite: Memory has been freed, but you're still referencing it as though it were valid. The problem you had here was an example of a dangling pointer.